# Blocky graphical issues and missing roads

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Essentially, I'm getting these uniform sized squares at random spots in the graphics. (See images below.) They happen at near and far distances, and more consistently at night. Also, the road just likes to disappear. This happens in Online and Story mode. I've played around with AA and DX settings, but haven't been able to change much.

My system specs:

- Windows 8.1
- AMD Athlon II X4 630
- AMD Radeon HD 7800 (2 GB)
- 20 GB RAM

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]
[image: Pic3]
[image: Pic4]

Comment: I'd first try verifying the integrity of your game cache files. I'd also try updating your graphics card driver. However, this also looks like your graphics card might be failing. Is this happening in any other games?

Comment: Updated everything last night. I switched from DX11 to 10.1 back to 11, and it seemed to fix most of the squares for some reason... but the road is still missing at times. I haven't noticed anything like this in other games though.

Comment: You also verified the integrity of the game cache files?

Comment: Yeah, I did it when I was updating my drivers. I'll do it again. Cant hurt.

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like either you have a faulty/failing graphics card or some other issue where your graphics card can't handle the shaders in the game. If it gets worse and appears in more games, it's definitely signs of a failing GPU. In that case, you may want to have it replaced if it's still under warranty, otherwise look up baking your graphics card (yes, I literally mean putting it inside an oven). But only do that if you see it happening in other games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I fixed it. I don't know what steps actually helped, but I'll post it anyway.

- Running GTA5.exe in "High Priority" from the Task Manager *Most important*
- Switching DX Version to 11, then to 10.1, then back to 11.

#### Game Settings:

- Screen Type: Windowed Borderless
- FXAA: On
- MSAA: Off
- Vsync: Off
- Pause on Focus Loss: On
- Pop Density: 10%
- Population Variety: 100%
- Distance Scaling: 10%
- Texture: V. High
- Shader: High
- Shadow: High
- Reflection: High
- Reflection MSAA: Off
- Water: High
- Particles: High
- Grass: High
- Shadows: Soft
- Post FX: High
- Motion Blur: 0%
- Anisotropic: X2
- Occlusion: High
- Tessellation: High

Comment: good to hear you fixed your problem :) You can mark your own answer (or any answer) as 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark underneath the vote count. This will help future visitors know what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card may be damaged, this happened when I played tf2. It may also be that your graphics card can't handle the game and you should either upgrade your card, or lower the "terrain rendering"